# How can I calculate the percentage of each value in every row?

Tags: python

Here is my dataframe:
[image]

How can I generate a new dataframe that has all the values in percentage? For example, the Retro of Cab Monitor shows the percentage of the sum(Retro + Other + Overtime + Injured + Detail + Quinn). I know there are some ways to calculate the percentage of sum of the column, but I want to get the percentage of sum of the row. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

You can sum along rows and then use the sum to compute percentage easily on every column

```py
df['Total']= df.sum(axis=0)
for col in df.columns:
    df[col] = df[col] / df['Total']
```